# Internal Error !scandr.cpp @1952 in autocad2015

Tags: c#, autocad

I am trying to export the drawing to save another drawing using "CopyBase" and "PasteClip" command. But it is does not work an error occurred. Can anyone tell how to i solve this..

i am using Copy and Paste command like this..

```
 AcadApplication acadApp;
 AcadDocument thisdrawing;         

 acadApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application.20") as AcadApplication;
 acadApp.Visible = true;
 thisdrawing= acadApp.ActiveDocument;
 thisdrawing.Activate();
string str = "_CopyBase" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13) + "0,0,0" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13) + "M" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13) + "G" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13) + "QWERT" + "\n" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13);
thisdrawing.SendCommand(str);

  string  dwgTempPath = "acad.dwt";
         newThisdrawing = acapp.Documents.Add(dwgTempPath ) ;
         newThisdrawing.SaveAs(expDwgName , thisdrawing.Application.Preferences.OpenSave.SaveAsType,null);
         newDwgCreatBool = true;
         newThisdrawing.Regen(AcRegenType.acActiveViewport);
newthisdrawing.Activate();
comStr = "pasteclip" + "\n" + "0,0" + "\n";
newThisdrawing.SendCommand(comStr);
```

Thanks in Advance..

[image]

Comment: I've seen this before (not with copy/paste commands though).  Where I remember seeing it is with how the databases were handled.  Do you mind showning how you've gotten thisdrawing and newthisdrawing?  Are you copying everything into the new drawing?  Also, why COM? Need more info.

Comment: Here's a link to deep cloning from one drawing to another using the AutoCAD .NET API: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/09/copying-deepcloning-from-one-drawing-to-another-using-net.html

Comment: thanks mr.bjhuffine. Above i have mentioned how thisdrawing and newthisdrawing get assigned. we Already developed this export tool. It working fine from 2007 to 2014. But 2015 this error is coming..

Comment: `CopyObjects` method should be more efficient and more reliable than Copy/Paste commands. What happens if there are no QWERT group in the drawing?

Answer (score 0):

With your edit, I'm assuming this is an external exe.  With that in mind and some minor modifications to your code, I got this to work with no problems in a Console exe.  Before the code a couple things about it:

- I compiled using the 4.5 Framework.  The COM references for .NET may have been updated with their .NET API counterparts, so make sure this is the case for you too.
- Add a COM reference to "AutoCAD 2015 Type Library"  there's one for each language package (choose axdb20enu.tlb, but I think in the end VS may select them all after it's added).
- Add a COM reference to "AcObjClassImp 1.0 Type Library", choose the one for release 20 (AcObjClassImp20.tlb)

  - Add the using statement "using AutoCAD;" at the top with the rest.

Here's the code I used:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAcadApplication acadApp;
        IAcadDocument thisdrawing;

        acadApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application.20") as AcadApplication;
        acadApp.Visible = true;
        thisdrawing = acadApp.ActiveDocument;
        thisdrawing.Activate();
        string str = "_CopyBase" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13) + "0,0,0" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13) + "M" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13) + "G" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13) + "QWERT" + "\n" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13);
        thisdrawing.SendCommand(str);

        string dwgTempPath = "acad.dwt";
        IAcadDocument newThisdrawing = acadApp.Documents.Add(dwgTempPath);

        //Instead of the path below, use your full path, formatted correctly
        newThisdrawing.SaveAs(@"C:\Acad\Test.dwg", thisdrawing.Application.Preferences.OpenSave.SaveAsType, null);

        newThisdrawing.Regen(AcRegenType.acActiveViewport);
        newThisdrawing.Activate();
        string comStr = "pasteclip" + "\n" + "0,0" + "\n";
        newThisdrawing.SendCommand(comStr);
    }
```

Comment: i tried IAcadDocument  still i got same error.. I don't know why it's happening help me to solve this..

Comment: Did you verify all your references to be correct?  There should be three:  AutoCAD, AXDBLib, and ObjClassImpLib.  All three are derived by adding the two COM references I mentioned earlier.  When my company migrates they remove the previous versions so I can't verify that would cause the issue, but seems a reasonable assumption.  Are you using the 4.5 version framework?  If you want to test the code above, create a Console app, copy the code into the Main() method, add the references, and it works.  When you run it, start AutoCAD first, then the console app.  You can even run it in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks  bjhuffine..i got solution.. I am using  thisdrawing.CopyObjects(arrylist, newThisdrawing.ModelSpace,  Type.Missing);  So this line fixed my problem.. Thanks lot..Yes i referenced the assembly correctly. and I have run it in framework4.5 only..